# Java single thread of execution and cpu cache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, cpu

Assume my application has only one thread and the platform on which the application runs has several CPUs. It is possible that the single thread of application at some point of time executes on cpu A , reads the value of property X, modifies its value and the modified value of property X is not committed to main memory, it just resides on cpu registry or cache. Then after some time the same thread of application can continue its flow on cpu B, read the value of property X and get the stale value from main memory, as the updated value resides on cpu A registry/cache.

So till now i saw everywhere that such kind of visibility problems occur only in multithreaded apps but seems that in case i have described that is possible as well.

Any idea ?

Comment: If it was multi threaded, it was possible for sure as cache memory of a core is not visible to other processor. However, In single threaded, I don't think it is possible as Java itself do not act on core directly . Instead, it creates an OS associated thread and the OS is responsible for scheduling/running your thread . So I believe all widely used OS are smart enough to handle this scenario which could be just assigning its thread to particular core until it dies as there is no need to assign a same thread to multiple core.

Comment: I think that OS can assign the thread to different CPUs/cores during the lifetime of thread, so if it's true then your answer doesn't point to the solution

Comment: If you are talking about rights, OS can definitely assign a thread to any of the core. But there won't be a need to execute a single thread in multiple core . Lets say there comes a weird scenario where OS finds it best to run the thread in new core, then it should be able to copy all the cached information associated with the thread to the other core. So basically, if you are running a single threaded java application, there won't be such  stale cached data as you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java language definition says there is a "happens before" relationship between anything that happens earlier in a thread and anything that happens later in the same thread.  This means that it is the responsibility of the JVM, working with the operating system, to ensure visibility of any data written earlier in the thread to any operations later in the same thread.  On most operating systems, I believe this would be handled at the operating system level, by saving register state and flushing cache to memory when a thread is switched out.  In any case, you don't have to worry about it when writing Java code.

Comment: Agree. In context of concurrent applications, every resource available in the net describes the visibility problem telling that if the threads are lacking proper synchronization then variable value modified by one thread can reside in cpu cache, not being flushed to main memory, and another thread executing on another cpu/core cannot see that value. So, in case of proper synchronization the solution is to flush modified values to main memory. But what about the case of single thread, how various JVMs implement JLS happens before in that case ?